# Как создать архив с файлами и папками в qt, используяю библиотеку quazip

Tags: qt5

Всем привет!
Возникли трудности с созданием архива, который содержит и папки и файлы.
Использую qt5 и библиотеку quazip.

Заминка в том, что используя JlCompress::compressFiles(QString fileCompressed, QStringList files) создается архив только с файлами, без папок (Судя по докам так и должно быть).

Чтобы сделать архив папки используется bool JlCompress::compressDir(QString fileCompressed, QString dir, bool recursive, QDir::Filters filters)

Все методы прекрасно работают! Но как сделать архив И с файлами И с папками??

Comment: Видимо надо задать последний параметр в `QDir::AllEntries` тогда упакует все

Comment: Да это использовал и работает все прекрасно. НО это работает если есть например /home/user/folder и эта folder содержит какие либо папки и файлы. Но как заархивировать если есть /home/user/folder и /home/user/file. чтобы архив содержал folder и file.

Comment: Наверное надо вот это указать в качестве корня `/home/user/`

Comment: Хорошо, а если есть в этом каталоге например /home/user/file2 который не надо архивировать? Пока единственным решением пришло в голову, копировать файлы во временную папку и архивировать ее...

Comment: Создаете во временной директории копию и в нее копируете то, что вам нужно, соответственно делаете из этого архив